# How to retrieve ALL files deleted from a folder (where the folder does not appear in checkouts anymore)

Tags: cvs

Someone has deleted the following files from cvs repository

m2\file1.txt

m2\file2.txt

m2\file3.txt

m2, which had only those three files, and is a folder under project1.

I need to recover those deleted files.
So I check out project1 on my windows workspace. I don't see the folder m2.
But when i login to the cvs server (linux), i can see the

project1\m2  folder, containing only the Attic (containing those 3 files).

As per [How do I restore a deleted file in CVS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144669/how-do-i-restore-a-deleted-file-in-cvs)
 i am supposed to go into the m2 folder ( in my windows workspace)and run

cvs add

and

cvs commit

My problem is that I don't even see the m2 folder (in windows and I use tortoiseCVS), for me to run the above two commands.
These commands work on folders which are non empty.

How do i recover first the folder and then these files either in windows workspace or linux (I've tried moving the files from the Attic to the parent m2 folder on the cvs server, but that does not show up in my windows workspace).

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `-d` option but not the `-P` option to `cvs update` so that it gets all directories on the server but doesn't prune empty ones.  Then you should be able to use the `add` commands to resurrect the files.